# Let $S$ be the set numbers whose digits are chosen from ${1, 3, 5, 7}$ such that no digits are repeated. Find the sum of every element in $S$.

Tags: combinatorics

All numbers in $S$ are natural. I could find the $|S| = 64$ by my own. Can't find the sum of every number in $S$, nor understand the book's explanation for that. The answer is $117856$.

Taken from Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics.

Answer (score 7):

Let us define $n=1+3+5+7=16$.  The one digit numbers in $S$ sum to $n$.  There are $4 \cdot 3$ two digit numbers in $S$, so each digit appears in each column (ones and tens) three times. The sum of the two digit numbers is then $3(10+1)n=33n=528$.  There are $24$ three digit numbers, so each digit appears in each column six times, so the sum is $6\cdot 111 \cdot n=10656$.  Finally there are $24$ four digit numbers, so the sum is $6\cdot 1111 \cdot n=106656$.  The total is $106656+10656+528+16=117856$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't understand this step, though "The sum of the two digit numbers is then $3(10+1)n=33n=528$, it's a similar approach took by the author in the book, which is what I don't get. Could you please elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: "There are $4 \cdot 3$ two-digit numbers in S, so each digit appears in each column three times." It's based on the number of permutations of 2 numbers from the set being $4\times3=12$, and by making an argument to symmetry you know that each of the 4 digits appears an equal number of times in those numbers in each decimal place, so they must each appear 3 times. Hence, the sum of the 2-digit numbers is 3 times the sum of putting each digit in both the 10s and 1s places, hence $3(10+1)n$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and time, ConMan, I finally get it.

Answer (score 6):

First consider all the four digit numbers formed by these.

Digit 1 will occur in the 1000th place value for 6 numbers (when we permute 3,5,7 in the other three places, the numbers are 1357, 1375, 1735, 1753, 1573, 1537), 100th place value for 6 numbers, 10th place for 6 numbers and units place for 6 numbers. Similar for the other digits. Thus the total is $6 \times (1+3+5+7) \times (1000+100+10+1) = 106656$.

Similar argument for three digit, two digit and 1 digit numbers.

Comment: This gets the four digit numbers, but you have to consider numbers with fewer digits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Please, read my comment in the Ross Millikan's answer, since both of your approaches are similar.

Comment: Consider any two of the digits, $a,b$. The sum of two digit numbers formed by them is 10a+b + 10b+a = 11a+11b. Thus the sum of all two digit numbers that could be formed from $1,3,5,7$ is same as $11$ times the sum of pairs of numbers chosen from $1,3,5,7$. These pairs are $(1,3), (1,5), (1,7), (3,5), (3,7), (5,7)$. Thus the sum of two digit numbers is $11(1+3+1+5+1+7+3+5+3+7+5+7) = 11\times 3 \times (1+3+5+7)$

Answer (score 0):

You deal with the cases individually, noting that S=1+3+5+7 makes 16.

For numbers starting with 1, we note there are 3*2*1 four-digit numbers, 3*2 three-digit numbers, 3 2-digit numbers and 1 one-digit number, or 6+6+3+1 = 16 numbers.

Since this is true for each member of S individually, there are thus 64 such numbers.

We note that the position that the digits are equally spread in the digits, and that the average is then S/4 per digit, ie 4

We find that there are 24 four-digit numbers, 24 three-digit numbers, 12 two-digit numbers, and 4 one-digit number, giving 12(2222+222+11)+4 12*2455 + 4, or 117856, all together.

Comment: The question asks for the sum of these $64$ numbers.

Comment: saw this: fixed,